# PHP Tidy encodes comment

Tags: php, tidy

I am making use of PHP tidy and I've been given a situation where a user has placed a comment within a href attribute, like so:

```
<a href="<!-- Comment -->">Link</a>
```

When I pass it through Tidy, it returns:

```
<a href="&lt;!-- Comment --&gt;">Link</a>
```

I am guessing this is Tidy's way of correcting this? It makes sense, but is there a way to stop this behaviour, other than not using Tidy?!

I have tried switching on/off the configuration options: `literal-attributes`, `fix-bad-comments` and `preserve-entities`. But these do not seem to turn off this effect

Comment: Um, maybe only link to actual links?

Comment: @Cyclone - you might want to give me the benefit of the doubt. The comment is used for other purposes.

Comment: Sorry, I've just never seen anyone put comments in the href of a link before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is valid HTML even. You can't put tags inside attribute values.

Comment: It is valid code, I put it through the W3C validator and it got a pass! I didn't think it was valid either! For some doc types I should add. It's not valid for xHTML.

Comment: There are a lot of things which are valid, but which Tidy will intentionally not accept. For instance, some SGML shorthands like `<hr<img src=...>` are technically valid in HTML (before HTML5), but Tidy will rewrite them anyways, as they may not be parsed correctly by some agents.

Answer (score 0):

Before passing the html through PHP tidy, look for comments (regexp, perhaps?) and encode them somehow. Then unencode after using tidy.

One example of how to encode comments would be to set the href as `comment://n`, where n is the index of the original comment text, which is stored in an array.